# ¿Como puedo cambiar el fondo de un TextInputDialog en JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-css

Estoy intentando usar un cuadro de dialogo en javaFx donde el usuario puede ingresar información por teclado, he intentado creando una ventana que se abra al mismo tiempo que la anterior lo esté pero no he podido. Descubrí la clase TextInputDialog para usarla como ventana pero resulta que no le puedo modificar el color de fondo, quisiera aplicarle algo de css pero no sé como podría hacerlo en esta clase.

```
public String leerTextoUsandoTextInput(String mensaje) {
        TextInputDialog td = new TextInputDialog();
        td.setHeaderText(mensaje);
        td.getGraphic().applyCss();
        td.showAndWait();
        return td.getContentText();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede mediante un método `TextInputDialog.getDialogPane()`que devuelve el nodo raíz que es un objeto de la clase `DialogPane` . A dicho objeto se le puede declarar propiedades  css   pasándole un `String` con dichas propiedades y valores al método `.setStyle()` de esta manera :

```
public String leerTextoUsandoTextInput(String mensaje) {
            TextInputDialog td = new TextInputDialog();
            td.setHeaderText(mensaje);
             // en este caso el color cyan 
            td.getDialogPane().setStyle("-fx-background-color:cyan;");
            td.getGraphic().applyCss();
            td.showAndWait();
            return td.getContentText();
        }
```

[image: salida]

pero DialogPane tiene muchos nodos anidados dentro de él . Otra manera es darle al diálogo una clase para poder darle reglas en un archivo css y así acceder a todos los nodos a través de sus selectores en css

```
public String leerTextoUsandoTextInput(String mensaje) {
        TextInputDialog td = new TextInputDialog();
        td.setHeaderText(mensaje);
        td.getDialogPane().getStyleClass().add("td");
        td.getDialogPane().getStylesheets().add("td.css");
        td.getGraphic().applyCss();
        td.showAndWait();
        return td.getContentText();
    }
```

el archivo td.css :

```
 .td{
    -fx-background-color: cyan;
}
.td > *.button-bar > *.container{
    -fx-background-color: cyan;
}

.td:header *.header-panel{
    -fx-background-color: cyan;
}
```

[image: dialogpane con css]

Comment: Muchas gracias, tienes toda la razón. Me sirvió mucho

Comment: swing está incluida en javafx más por retrocompatibilidad con programas antiguos  que por otra . no recomiendo usar jframe , jpanel, etc ... si esta la funcionalidad de javafx

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacerlo con un JOptionPane:

```
String frase = null;
    UIManager UI = new UIManager();
    UI.put("OptionPane.background", Color.white);
    UI.put("Panel.background", Color.white);

    frase = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Texto que quieras");
```

Importa las clases que te pida y lo tendrias!
Tienes mas informacion por aqui(En ingles) -->[Change BG color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064943/how-to-change-background-color-of-joptionpane)

Un saludo!